# Android Hexagon Grid

Tags: android, gridview

I need to develop an app in which buttons are hexagons and all of them are placed next to each other creating a grid. Given my little experience in Android, I wonder if GridView is the best approach for this. If that is the case, how could I place the hexagons next to each other?

I have this by now

[image]

Using this layout in main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:columnWidth="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="top"
/>
```

And this is what I am trying to get:

[image: hexagon grid]

I would need some help to place hexagons tied to each other in a fixed structure. I've been playing around with the layout values with no sucess. Would TableView be a better approach?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.gdreflections.com/2011/02/hexagonal-grid-math.html) very good article that also has nice Java samples. You can probably adapt them to Android.

Comment: Where is the `HexView`-View from?

Comment: I just confused the name of the app with the GridView layout when editing the post - corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some code I used in an app (it's called 'Connect3, if you'd like to play it :) ). It is a custom layout class that draws hexagonal images in a grid. The grid can be triangular or a tilted rectangle.

The code calculates the bounds (in pixels relative to the origin of the hexgrid) of each imageview and then calls `imageView.layout(left,top,right,bottom)` to set the calculated bounds. The calculations aren't that hard. The main parameter is the `radius` of the hexagon. From that, the total hight, total width, effective hight and effective width (the height/width of the imageview respectively the distance between the top/left bounds of two consecutive views). Then it comes down to some simple for loops to draw them.

To make the views clickable, just set an `onClickListener` when you create them. (I made it a class member, because it made things easier).

The `onMeasure` functions just calculates the total width and height of the view and calls `setMeasuredDimension` with those values.

The images used for all this are just the single hexagons as you see them right below the actionbar. Note that the images are squares.

```
    @Override
protected void onLayout(final boolean changed, final int l, final int t, final int r, final int b) {
    Log.d(TAG, "board.onlayout called with size "+mSize+" l: "+l+" r: "+r+" t: "+t+" b: "+b);

    //If the dimensions of the board haven't changed, a redraw isn't necessary. Just update the images of the views instead by calling invalidate().
    if (!changed && !mSizeInvalidated) {
        invalidate();
        return;
    }
    int childCount = getChildCount();

    //Calculate some useful parameters.
    float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radius);
    float verticalMargin = -radius / 4;
    float horizontalMargin = ((float) Math.sqrt(3) / 2 - 1) * radius;
    float height = 2 * radius;
    float width = height;
    float effectiveHeight = height + 2 * verticalMargin;
    float effectiveWidth = width + 2 * horizontalMargin;

    float totalHeight=(radius * (3 * mSize + 1)) / 2;
    float totalWidth;
    switch (mGameType) {
        case Connect3Turn.GAME_TYPE_HEX:
            totalWidth = (((float) mSize * 3  - 1)/ 2) * ((float) Math.sqrt(3)) * radius;
            break;
        case Connect3Turn.GAME_TYPE_Y:
        default:
            totalWidth = mSize * ((float) Math.sqrt(3)) * radius;
    }

    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams((int) width, (int) height);

    //Code to calculate the offsets for horizontal and vertical centering (this is an option in the .xml file)
    //The GAME_TYPE_HEX creates a tilted rectangular board and GAME_TYPE_Y creates a triangular board.
    float x_offset_row;
    switch (mGameType) {
        case Connect3Turn.GAME_TYPE_Y:
            x_offset_row=(mSize - 1) * effectiveWidth / 2 + horizontalMargin;
            break;
        case Connect3Turn.GAME_TYPE_HEX:
        default:
            x_offset_row=0;
    }
    switch (mCenterHorizontal) {
        //the left side of the grid should be at non-negative coordinates.
        case 1: {
            x_offset_row += Math.max(0,(r-l-totalWidth)/2);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {x_offset_row += Math.max(0,(r-l-totalWidth));
            break;
        }
        case 0:
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }

    //calculate the y_offset for vertical centering.
    float y_offset = 0;
    switch (mCenterVertical) {
        case 1: {
            y_offset = Math.max(0, (b - t - totalHeight) / 2);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            y_offset = Math.max(0, (b - t -totalHeight));
            break;
        }
    }


    int cell = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < mSize; ++row) {
        float x_offset = x_offset_row;
        int rowLength;
        //The row length depends on the board-type we want to draw.
        switch (mGameType){
            case Connect3Turn.GAME_TYPE_HEX:
                rowLength=mSize;
                break;
            case Connect3Turn.GAME_TYPE_Y:
            default:
                rowLength=row+1;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Drawing row "+row+" with "+rowLength+" cells.");
        for (int col = 0; col < rowLength; ++col) {
            ImageView v;
            if (cell < childCount) {
                v = (ImageView) getChildAt(cell);
            } else {
                v = new ImageView(super.getContext());
                v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                v.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
                addViewInLayout(v, cell, v.getLayoutParams(), true);
            }

            //Set the image (color) of the cell and put its index in a tag, so we can retrieve the number of the clicked cell in the onClickListener.
            v.setImageResource(mImageIds[mImages[cell]]);
            v.setTag(cell);

            //Set the bounds of the image, which will automatically be cropped in the available space.
            v.layout((int) x_offset, (int) y_offset, (int) (x_offset + width), (int) (y_offset + height));
            x_offset += effectiveWidth;
            ++cell;
        }
        y_offset += effectiveHeight;
        //The offset of the next row, relative to this one, again depends on the game type.
        switch(mGameType){
            case Connect3Turn.GAME_TYPE_Y:
                x_offset_row -= effectiveWidth / 2;
                break;
            case Connect3Turn.GAME_TYPE_HEX:
                x_offset_row += effectiveWidth / 2;
        }
    }

    //We updated all views, so it is not invalidated anymore.
    mSizeInvalidated=false;
}
```

[image: hexgrid1]
[image: hexgrid2]

Answer (score -2):

You can always work with it like if it was a normal grid. But instead of drawing a square, you draw an hexagon.

http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/9229/uyje.png

But then, you move the odd lines half the width of the hexagon in a way that they will fit with the pair lines.

http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/2298/e5cq.png