# How to create hexagon listview in android

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm looking to create hexagon listview like this. [image]

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840729/android-hexagon-grid). Maybe this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this hexagonal imageview in child layout and adjust margins

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HexagonMaskView extends ImageView {
    private Path hexagonPath;
    private Path hexagonBorderPath;
    private Paint mBorderPaint;

    public HexagonMaskView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public HexagonMaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public HexagonMaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.hexagonPath = new Path();
        this.hexagonBorderPath = new Path();

        this.mBorderPaint = new Paint();
        this.mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.mBorderPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        this.mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(50f);
        this.mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    public void setRadius(float radius) {
        calculatePath(radius);
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int color) {
        this.mBorderPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    private void calculatePath(float radius) {
        float halfRadius = radius / 2f;
        float triangleHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3.0) * halfRadius);
        float centerX = getMeasuredWidth() / 2f;
        float centerY = getMeasuredHeight() / 2f;

        this.hexagonPath.reset();
        this.hexagonPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radius);
        this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY + halfRadius);
        this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY - halfRadius);
        this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radius);
        this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY - halfRadius);
        this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY + halfRadius);
        this.hexagonPath.close();

        float radiusBorder = radius - 5f;
        float halfRadiusBorder = radiusBorder / 2f;
        float triangleBorderHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3.0) * halfRadiusBorder);

        this.hexagonBorderPath.reset();
        this.hexagonBorderPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY + halfRadiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY - halfRadiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY - halfRadiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY + halfRadiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.close();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.drawPath(hexagonBorderPath, mBorderPaint);
        c.clipPath(hexagonPath, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
        c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        calculatePath(Math.min(width / 2f, height / 2f) - 10f);
    }
}
```

in xml

```
  <YourpakageName.HexagonMaskView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/bear"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
```

hope this helps

Comment: this for imageview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601400/how-to-give-hexagon-shape-to-imageview

Comment: ya he can use that image view for list child view ,and add some margins (positive and negative ) based on even odd positions

Comment: I understand .But user asking `How to create hexagon listview`

Comment: how can a List view be hexagonal?  it can be either horizontal or vertical , he ment about image view in his question i guess

Comment: @Indeed Indeed .Then Question statement is Mistake oriented

Comment: Redman your solution not works for me.  not display anything in .XML

Comment: Did you initialize image view correctly in Main activity,  You have to take `HexagonMaskView imageview=(HexagonMaskView)findViewById(R.id.imageview)`    dont take image view

Comment: Glad it helped,Please consider upvoting answer so people can reach answer easily :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey use Vector image for that:-

```
<vector android:height="24dp"
android:viewportHeight="628.0"
android:viewportWidth="726.0"
android:width="27dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path
    android:fillColor="#00ffffff"
    android:pathData="m723,314c-60,103.9 -120,207.8 -180,311.8 -120,0 -240,0 -360,0C123,521.8 63,417.9 3,314 63,210.1 123,106.2 183,2.2c120,0 240,0 360,0C603,106.2 663,210.1 723,314Z"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeWidth="4" />
```

Hope this help.Happy coding.